# How do I classify the brand name of a product using Machine Learning?

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, classification

I have a shop filled with 26597 unique products.

The data I use to import the products into the shop looks something like this:

```
{  
   "description":"AH Uien rood",
   "category":"/Aardappel, groente, fruit/Kruiden, uien, knoflook/Uien/",
   "brand":"AH"
}, {...}
```

530 of the 26597 products don't have the `brand` value. However, the brand name is present in the description. For the above example product, in `"description":"AH Uien rood"`, `AH` is the brand name of. The brand name is always the first 1+ words in the description. But brand names vary in length and word size, and often have spaces in between. Therefore I cannot simply extract the first word from the description and assign it as the product brand name.

I figured I'd use Machine Learning to help me classify product brand names based on the description and category.

It's my first real experience with Machine Learning, and I decided to use the [ai4r](https://github.com/SergioFierens/ai4r) Ruby gem. It looks good, is well maintained and properly documented [here](http://ai4r.org/rdoc/index.html).

For 530 products only 13 get sort of classified, the rest return the error:

```
Ai4r::Classifiers::ModelFailureError: There was not enough information during training to do a proper induction for the data element ...
```

Which I don't quite understand, the size of `DATA_SET`, which is used to train the model, is 25266.

This is what my code looks like:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
require 'ai4r'

r = JSON.parse(open('http://goo.gl/2IHtVU') {|f| f.read }.force_encoding('UTF-8'))

def extract_categories(product)
  a = product['category'].split('/')
  a.delete('')
  b = []
  a.each { |category| b << category.gsub(',', ' -') }
  c = b.join(', ')
end

nb = []
r.each {|p| nb << p if p['brand'].nil? }

DATA_LABELS = ["title", "category", "brand"]

DATA_SET = []
r.each {|pnb| DATA_SET << [pnb['description'], extract_categories(pnb), pnb['brand']] unless pnb['brand'].nil? || pnb['category'].nil? }

data_set = Ai4r::Data::DataSet.new(:data_items=>DATA_SET, :data_labels=>DATA_LABELS)
id3 = Ai4r::Classifiers::ID3.new.build(data_set)

classified = []

nb.each do |pnb|
  begin
    classified << id3.eval([ pnb['description'], extract_categories(pnb) ])
  rescue => e
      puts 'There was not enough information during training to do a proper induction for the data element, moving on...'
  end
end

classified.size
# => 13

# Save DATA_SET to csv
# CSV.open('/data_set.csv','wb', :quote_char => '"', encoding: "UTF-8") do |csv|
#   csv << DATA_LABELS
#
#   DATA_SET.each do |data|
#     csv << [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
#   end
# end
#
# => https://gist.github.com/narzero/ba8c521a370326a57a68
```

What is a better way to classify the brand name of a product based on the description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for a Naive-Bayes classifier instead of a decision tree in this case. There is a gem for it. [stuff-classifier](https://github.com/alexandru/stuff-classifier)

In the code below I trained your data set with the gem and classified 10 random entries. I used the description for training and not the categories. See how the performance is. Otherwise you can include the categories by combining the categories into the desciption but prepending the category token with something like cattt to distinguish the category tokens from the description.

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'stuff-classifier'


r = JSON.parse(open('data_file.json') {|f| f.read }.force_encoding('UTF-8'))

def extract_categories(product)
  a = product['category'].split('/')
  a.delete('')
  b = []
  a.each { |category| b << category.gsub(',', ' -') }
  c = b.join(', ')
end

nb = []
r.each {|p| nb << p if p['brand'].nil? }

DATA_LABELS = ["title", "category", "brand"]

DATA_SET = []
r.each {|pnb| DATA_SET << [pnb['description'], extract_categories(pnb), pnb['brand']]     unless pnb['brand'].nil? || pnb['category'].nil? }



cls = StuffClassifier::Bayes.new("Prodcut Label")

#train the classifier by feeding it the label and then the features
DATA_SET.each do |record|
    begin
        cls.train(record[2], record[0])
    rescue
    end 
end

# print 10 random classifications

1.upto(10){
    random_entry = DATA_SET.sample[0]
    puts "#{random_entry} - Classified as - #{cls.classify(random_entry)}"
}
```

Results:

- Organix Goodies squeezy banaan, aardbei & zuivel - Classified as - Organix
- AH Dames hipster elastisch zwart maat M => John Cabot / AH
- Piramide Sterrenmix fair trade => - Piramide
- Royal Club Bitter lemon => Royal Club
- AH Fruitbiscuit yoghurt/ aardbei => AH
- Toni & Guy Mask reconstruction treatment => Toni & Guy
- AH Kinder enkelsok wit mt  23-26 => AH
- Theramed Aardbei junior 6+ jaar => Theramed
- Arla Bio drinkyoghurt limoen/ munt => Arla
- AH Rauwkost Amsterdamse ui => AH

Comment: I would use simple prefix tree because it is way easier and precise.